# how **(1)** $(2n-1)\pi/2 + (-1)^n\pi/3$ and **(2)** $2n\pi±\pi/6$ indicates the same angle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm learning Trigonometry right now with myself and at current about **General solution**. I have a question in my book which I don't understand how to proof. **The question is**
 *Show that the two angles are indicated by the two following formulae -* 
**(1)** $(2n-1)\pi/2 + (-1)^n\pi/3$ and **(2)** $2n\pi±\pi/6$ 
I don't know how to proof this, there is no trigonometry ratio given. Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: maybe draw a picture, i.e. a circle and illustrate the angles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the two cases of $n$ even and $n$ odd separately.

In other words, first put $n=2k+1$ into the first formula and simplify as much as possible. You should see that it is of the same form as the second formula.

Then do it again with $n=2k$.

**Note:** Evens and odds are commonly represented as $2k$ and $2k+1$, or as $2k$ and $2k-1$. Other representations are possible, but these are the most commonly used.

Comment: I have did it earlier the result coming when $n=2k+1$ is $2\pi k + \pi/6$.

Comment: Yes, and when you use $n=2k$ you should get $2\pi k - \pi/6$. So you are done, because together the totality of answers is $2\pi k \pm \pi/6$.

Comment: One more question why n should be equal to 2k+1 when odd and 2k when even. Is this expression is in the form of general expression of sine that's why?

Comment: @YogeshTripathi $2k+1$ is any general odd number. It is odd because 2 doesn't divide it.

Comment: when $n=2k+1$ the result coming is is $2\pi k + \pi/6$ but the second expression he n is place of K.

Comment: and if I take n =1 which is Odd then why it is not same as the second expression in which n is taken as 1 too.

Comment: Also if I take n=2k-1 for odd then also the result is different.

Comment: The same $n$ isn't going to appear in both expressions. The point is that the total collection of angles you get using all values of $n$ in either expression is the same. Every angle you can write in the first way with some $n$ can be written in the other way with some (possibly different) $n$, and vice versa. It's the *form* of the expression that they refer to in the answer.

Comment: Ok. And here 2k and 2k+1 are possible values of n only or we can take any other values like 2k-1 for odd?

Comment: @Yogesh of course

Comment: But why the results are different?

Comment: They are not different. The individual representation doesn't matter, the point is WHEN YOU PUT ALL THE OBTAINED ANGLES IN A BUCKET, YOU STILL HAVE THE SAME TOTAL COLLECTION OF ANGLES. You can use $2k+571$ for odd and $2k -7652$ for even and you have the same collection of angles as using $2k+1$ and $2k$. You realize you are letting $k$ range over all integers, not just picking a single integer, right? For example, the odd $15$ can be written as $2(-278)+571$ in the first representation, and $2(7)+1$ in the second representation.

Comment: Now I understand this. Just last question how you get to know that we should place 2k+1 for odd and 2k for even and not any other value. Any trick or experience?

Comment: An integer is even if and only if it is **some integer multiple** of $2$. An integer is odd if and only if it is $1$ more than **some even integer**. Another way to see this is that if you look at the set of all even integers, there is a single odd integer between each two successive evens. Shifting the set of evens to the right by one unit produces exactly the set of all odd integers. Thus $\mathbb Z$ is the disjoint union of $2\mathbb Z$ and $2\mathbb Z + 1$. So, for example $2\mathbb Z + 1$ and $2\mathbb Z + 3$ are exactly the same set.

Comment: I wanted to ask how you knew that 2k+1 will be placed in place of odd and 2k for even and not any other value like 2k-1.

Comment: Both work equally well, you just need to choose a representation and stick with it. Suppose you use $2k-1$. Then I can write $$2k-1 = 2k-2+1 = 2(\underbrace{k-1}_{\textrm{int }k'})+1=2k'+1$$ and in the other direction if I use $2k+1$ then you can write $$2k +2 - 1=2(\underbrace{k+1}_{\textrm{int }k'})-1=2k'-1$$ so each produces the same list of odd integers (all of them).

Comment: @MPW thankyou very much for your time. You have cleared my all confusions. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

For a visual proof, you can try drawing phase diagrams:

Choose $2$ values of $n$, one even and one odd (to get all possible outcomes from $-1^n$). Now sketch phase diagrams:

[image]

In order to prove that they both are indeed equal, do what MPW said.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify and work with integers, multiply all by $6/\pi$.

Then $3(2n-1)+2(-1)^n$ and $12n\pm1$ are $-1,1,11,13,23,25\cdots$ and $-1,1,11,13,23,25\cdots$.

Actually, the first formula reduces to the second with $2n,2n+1\leftrightarrow n$.

$$3(2\cdot2n-1)+2(-1)^{2n}=12n-3+2=12n-1,\\
3(2\cdot(2n+1)-1)+2(-1)^{2n+1}=12n+3-2=12n+1.$$